# make a for loop for linked list class

Tags: python, for-loop, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

i want to iterate over my custom class linked list, could anyone help me for that, i couldn't find it straightforward in web.

the problem is when i want to iterate over linked list its give me an error and said the linked list don't have a loop in it.

i want to make it iterable with `__iter__` and `__next__` or some other easier algorithms.

here are few lines of my code:

```
class node:
      def __init__(self, data=None):
          self.data = data
          self.next = None
class linkedList:
      def __init__(self):
         self.head = node()
         self._len = 0

      def add(value):
         self._len += 1
         newNode = node(value)
         curNode = self.head

         while curNode.next != None:
               curNode = curNode.next
         
         curNode.next = newNode
```

Comment: You already have a loop in the `add` method. What is the problem?

Comment: i want to do a loop over linked list after i filled it up , and for example:   for each in linked list print(each), did you get it?

Comment: I get it, but you already know how to loop over your list, because you did so in the `add` method. Why don't you use a similar pattern? What is the problem?

Comment: i have edited post, did you get the problem?

Comment: I get the problem, but what is the *problem* you have in implementing `__iter__`? What did you try? What went wrong?

Comment: i don't know how could i implement them in my case

Comment: That is a poor question. We appreciate it when a question shows effort. There seems to be none here.

Comment: You should not fix the question's code based on the answer. I reverted the last edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: your code doesn't work: `add` is missing the `self` parameter. It should be declared as `add(self, value)`.

To make your class instance iterable, define `__iter__`, and use a loop much like you have used in the `add` method, except that you don't need to look ahead in the `while` condition:

```
class linkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = node()
        self._len = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        curNode = self.head.next  # Skip head, as it is a dummy node
        while curNode:
            yield curNode.data
            curNode = curNode.next
```

Now you can use the feature that an instance is iterable:

```
lst = linkedList()
lst.add(19)
lst.add(33)
print(*lst)  # splash the values to print them
# or with a loop
for value in lst:
    print(value)
```

Comment: yeah, i missed self in add method. thanks for your answer